# Getting JavaScript Error "Cannot read property 'style' of null" in Dom Manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom, web

I just started learning DOM Manipulation and want to do a simple task of changing the font color of h1 using javaScript but I am getting this error - "Cannot read property 'style' of null ". My js file is connected to html but the next line is not working. Please help.

**demo.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Website</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**demo.js**

```
alert("connected");
var h1=document.querySelector("h1");
h1.style.color="pink";
```

Comment: Include the script after the DOM has loaded or wait for the DOM to be loaded

Comment: Thanks. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

you must load link your js at the end of body. you are mainpulating DOM but it hasn't loaded completely, thats why it is giving you null value. try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Site</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My Website</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js"></script>
</body>
```

or you can use defer in your script tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My Site</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="demo.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>My Website</h1>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

You must wait that the DOM is loaded.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){"put your code here"});
```